# Split or Drop dataframe / excel file by specific row in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have read multiple spreadsheet in python with pandas, however,there are two tables stored in the same spreadsheet.Because the entries are varied among different spreadsheets, therefore, I could't simply slice the Dataframe.
This is how I read the excel file.

```
#read all spreadsheets as dictionary
xls1819 = pd.read_excel('FilePath', sheet_name = None) 

#retrieve Dataframe from the dictionary

df0418 = xls1819['Apr 18'].iloc[:,:9] #select column 1 to column 9
df0518 = xls1819['May 18'].iloc[:,:9] #select column 1 to column 9
```

My questions is :I would like to drop the second table since that is short summary of the first table.
Can I find the row index by specific value such as v1 v2 v3 result and split the Dataframe into two tables or just keep the first table.

**table read from xlsx**

```
     v1    v2   v3   result
0    12    31   31        0
1    34    52    4        1
2    32     4    5        1
3     7    89    2        0
.
.
200  v1    v2   v3   result
201  sale  food 798  great
```

**Desired table**

```
     v1    v2   v3   result
0    12    31   31        0
1    34    52    4        1
2    32     4    5        1
3     7    89    2        0
```

Comment: I'm not sure  if I  understood correctly buy you can specify the sheet number in [`pd.read_excel(..., sheet_name=0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) or are you looking for [`pd.read_excel(..., skipfooter=2)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: After re-reading I guess you are looking for param `skipfooter`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, do you suggest that I should read each spreadsheet separately and manually check where the index duplicate column names are. Then I treat the second column name as footer and skip it?

There are 20 spreadsheets in the excel file, however the index are different. Do you think there would be other method to deal with this?